# *で２等辺三角形を作る

Tags: c

実行例を次のようにするにはどうすればいいでしょうか?
実行例：

```
./a.out
1辺：2
**
*
```

ちなみに、自分は以下のようにプログラムしました。

```
int main(void)
{
    int i,j,n;
    printf("一辺： ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=n;i>0;i=i-1){
       for(j=n;i<=j;j=j-1) {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 上記のコードを実行してみたのですが、、、「二等辺」三角形には見えませんね。。。[こんな感じ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4EbfKNov2LCNsICI)でしょうか？

Comment: コメント欄は回答欄ではないです。

Comment: 過去の質問も含め「期待する動作」に対する詳しい仕様と、「現状のプログラムではどんな問題があるのか」についての説明がそれぞれ必要じゃないかなと思います。 / 質問の仕方は [ヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) も参考にしてみてください。

Comment: 次々と質問している割にはコメントやBAのフォローが一切無いのが気になる

Comment: ご指摘いただいたBAフォローについてですが、BAフォローとはなんのことでしょうか。初心者なので簡単すぎる質問をしているかもしれませんが、教えていただければ幸いです。

Comment: "BA" は恐らく "ベストアンサー" の略ですが、スタック・オーバーフローでは「承認」と呼ばれる仕組みがあります。 / 質問に対して何らかのコメントや回答が付いた場合には、それらに適切なフォローをお願いします。 参考: [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: 承認すると回答した人の信用度(スコア)が上がるというのもありますし、そもそも「解決した」と言うことを伝えることにもなります。逆に回答の意味が解らなかったり筋違いだったりした場合は回答へのコメントにその旨を書くと、「ああ違うのか、じゃあこれならどうだ」とやる気が出るのではないかと。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問者の 2等辺三角形 (n=5)

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

回答者 774RR さんの ２等辺三角形 (n=5)

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

今回の案の ２等辺三角形 (n=5)

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```

n = 5 の場合
* の数は上から順番に
 1 , 3 , 5 , 7 , 9 個なので 式  2 * i - 1 （ i は 1 から n まで )
* の前のスペースの数は
 4 , 3 , 2 , 1 , 0 個なので 式  n - i （ i は 1 から n まで )

と まず大まかな、計画を立てて、それから ループを使ってプログラムを書きます。

```
// ２等辺三角形を描画する
void printTriangle(int n)
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        int width = i * 2 - 1;
        int prev_space_n = n - i;
        for(int j = 0; j < prev_space_n ; j++) {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < width ; j++) {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

参考までに、円もかけます。

```
void printCircle(int r)
{
    // x^2 + y^2 <= r^2 : 半径 r の 円を描画する
    int r2 = r * r;
    for(int x = -r ; x <= r ; x++) {
        for(int y = -r; y <= r; y++) {
            int d = x * x + y * y;
            if (d <= r2) {
                printf("*");
            } else {
                printf(" ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

r=15 の 円

```
               *
          ***********
        ***************
      *******************
     *********************
    ***********************
   *************************
   *************************
  ***************************
  ***************************
 *****************************
 *****************************
 *****************************
 *****************************
 *****************************
*******************************
 *****************************
 *****************************
 *****************************
 *****************************
 *****************************
  ***************************
  ***************************
   *************************
   *************************
    ***********************
     *********************
      *******************
        ***************
          ***********
               *
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。プログラムによっては、円も書くことができるなんて知りませんでした。驚きました！

Answer (score 1):

`*` の数からいうと直角二等辺三角形ではありますよね・・・いまどきのコンソール画面上はX軸とY軸でピッチが違うのでそう見えないだけで。で設問は、提示プログラムでは下のほうがX軸が長いんだけど、それを上のほうがX軸が長いにしたい、でしょうか。

とりあえず `for` の条件が一般的プログラマ（っつかオイラ）にとっては難しい（直観的でない）です。合計 `n` 行を出力したいのであれば `for (i=0; i<n; ++i)` のほうが素直、一般的でしょう。 [c](/questions/tagged/c) や [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) では `n` 個や `n` 回を表現するのに `[0..n)` の半開区間を多用するので今から慣れておくと吉。

で、ご要望の三角形は「左側に `*` がある」「１行目が `n` 個」なわけで、先の `for (i=0; i<n; ++i)` ループを採用するなら `i` 行目の `*` の数は「 `n-i` 個」です (`i` が `0` スタートであることに注意)

ここまで分析できればコード化は簡単で

```
for (i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    for (j=0; j<n-i; ++j) {
        putchar('*');
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。お返事遅れてすみません。上のほうがX軸を長くしたいということです。とても参考になりました。